# How practical is it to take a Collectivo to Xel'Ha park?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, sightseeing, mexico, amusement-parks

Between Playa Del Carmen and Tulum, a "Colectivo" service runs up and down the main highway. These are vehicles you can flag down and pay a small fee to drop you off at some later point along the road.

I'm interested in using a Colective service to get to the [Xel'ha lagoon/theme park](http://www.xelha.com/?langRedirect=1&_ga=1.12958644.2090700403.1438384838). My question is how well does this work - our experience so far has been that some attractions are right off the highway, making colectivo ideal. Some are off the highway but with a transport service (like Xcaret theme park) and some are a considerable walk off the highway, which normally wouldn't be an issue - but is proving one in August heat and humidity to those accustomed to northerly climates.

So the question is how well does using the colectivo work for visitng this attraction - especially as Xel'ha appears to be located at/off a major road junction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is: Fairly.

I didn't use a colectivo in the end myself - for our group and distance, a Taxi only cost 30 MXN more. The walk from the highway is real, but probably only 500m - 800m or so. There is a sidewalk on the highway overpass (if you need to get to/from that side of the road). Once over the highway there is a footpath seperated from the road to take you to the entrance.